# Only works on activesheet, but I need it to run on all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue with my VBA code, I need it to hide data for weeks that have not ended or occurred yet. My code looks like this

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets("TOTAL ISSUE DATA").Unprotect "1234"
Sheets("Cradle Pop").Unprotect "1234"
Sheets("Bad Graph").Unprotect "1234"
Sheets("No&Low Flow").Unprotect "1234"
Sheets("Block Curve").Unprotect "1234"
Sheets("No&Low Charge").Unprotect "1234"

Dim cell As Range
Rows.Hidden = False

For Each cell In Worksheets("TOTAL ISSUE DATA").Range("B2:B56")
    If cell.Value > Now Then
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next cell
For Each cell In Worksheets("Cradle Pop").Range("B2:B56")
    If cell.Value > Now Then
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next cell
For Each cell In Worksheets("Bad Graph").Range("B2:B56")
    If cell.Value > Now Then
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next cell
For Each cell In Worksheets("No&Low Flow").Range("B2:B56")
    If cell.Value > Now Then
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next cell
For Each cell In Worksheets("Block Curve").Range("B2:B56")
    If cell.Value > Now Then
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next cell
For Each cell In Worksheets("No&Low Charge").Range("B2:B56")
    If cell.Value > Now Then
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next cell

Sheets("TOTAL ISSUE DATA").Protect "1234"
Sheets("Cradle Pop").Protect "1234"
Sheets("Bad Graph").Protect "1234"
Sheets("No&Low Flow").Protect "1234"
Sheets("Block Curve").Protect "1234"
Sheets("No&Low Charge").Protect "1234"

End Sub
```

Column A has the Week #, Column B has the end date for that week, C-Z has my data. This code works, but it only works on the current sheet. I have to manually run the code on another sheet to get the result I need. The goal is to have the code run once the file is opened for all sheets, right now it just does the sheet that it opens to. I hope I did an alight job explaining it. Please ask if you got questions about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the part that works only for the `ActiveSheet` is `Rows.Hidden = False`, because everything else should be working.

Thus, if you want it to work for every sheet, then write something like this on the place of `Rows.Hidden = False`:

```
Sheets("TOTAL ISSUE DATA").Rows.Hidden = False
Sheets("Cradle Pop").Rows.Hidden = False
...etc
```

As you have noticed, if you do not specify the `Worksheet()` of the `Row`, it takes the `ActiveWorksheet` only.

Your code is can be easily upgraded - if you build a separate procedure, that takes the range as an input and then loops through its cells like this:

```
Public Sub HideRange(rangeToHide As Range)

    Dim myCell As Range    
    For Each myCell In rangeToHide
        If myCell > Now Then
             cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        'The condition can be made a bit fancier like this:
        'myCell.EntireRow.Hidden = myCell > Now
    Next myCell    
End Sub
```

And you can pass values to it like `HideRange Worksheets("Bad Graph").Range("B2:B56")`

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate it! It works and I tested it for next's data and it reported the correct numbers. Once again thank you.

Comment: @ChristianSutton - welcome. When you have time, consider putting your code here - https://codereview.stackexchange.com, you can probably learn a few tricks.